# How are half-winning or half-losing or refund states treated in a multibet form?

Tags: betting

How is the prize calculated when there are half-winning or half-losing or refund states in a multibet form?

Does it matter if more than one bet is a half-winner or a half-loser, or a combination of both?

Does this change if any of the bets should be refunded (regardless of reason for the refund)?